# Protect something against overdrawing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a drawn raster in a Panel which is only for adjustment. On this raster the user can build simple circuritys. I've added some features, so that the user can adjust the connections. The problem is that everything beyond is getting painted over. Is there any possibility to do something like that? 
I added 2 screenshots so it is more clear what I mean:

http://www.pic-upload.de/gal-337018/f5lsv1/1.html

Code:

```
private void UserMovesButton(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        if (FirstFinished != 0)
        {
            dummy.Color = MainPanel.BackColor;
            Start = connectionButtons[ActualIndex - 1].Location;
            drawline();
            Start = connectionButtons[ActualIndex + 1].Location;
            drawline();
        }
        dummy.Color = Color.Black;
        Control controlToMove = (Control)sender;
        controlToMove.BringToFront();
        controlToMove.Location = new Point(controlToMove.Location.X + e.Location.X - 10,
            controlToMove.Location.Y + e.Location.Y - 10);
        {
            Start = connectionButtons[ActualIndex - 1].Location;
            Stop.X = controlToMove.Location.X + e.Location.X - 10;
            Stop.Y = controlToMove.Location.Y + e.Location.Y - 10;
            FirstFinished = 1;
            drawline();
            Start = connectionButtons[ActualIndex + 1].Location;
            drawline();
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
}
```

(Connectionbuttons is a list which incldes the Buttons)

I already thought about using the z-axis, but drawline doesnt support something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your `drawLine()` method does, but I assume you use it to draw on a `UserControl`. That would not be the right approach. You should derive from a `UserControl`, override the [OnPaint()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx) method and do all painting there (starting with the bottommost objects). To make sure that `OnPaint()` gets called after making changes to the data structure, you can use the `Invalidate()` or `Refresh()` method of the `UserControl`.